# A virtual function that must be overridden

Tags: c++

Consider a base class `class Base` which has a function `virtual void foo(void)`. This function is implemented in `Base`; i.e. is not pure virtual.

Is there a pattern I can use which when inheriting from this class, i.e. `class Child : public Base`, compels me to override `foo`?

Comment: Why would it be implemented if you wanted it to be overridden no matter what?

Comment: Because it's perfectly fine to have a `Base` instance (to model default behaviour). I was thinking in terms of having a pure virtual function with a function body but unsure of the effect. Plus I want to be able to instantiate `Base`s.

Comment: How can you compel someone to override foo, yet also allow foo to be instantiated (i.e. without overriding it)? It sounds like you've contradicted yourself.

Comment: If you want a base implementation that the subclass expands on but can't replace, the Template Method Pattern is your answer.

Answer (score 7):

Other than making it a pure virtual function, there is no way to make the override required.

Note that the fact that a function is marked pure virtual does not mean that it cannot have an implementation in the base class - it means only that the derived class *must* override it.

```
struct Base {
    virtual void foo() = 0; // foo() is pure virtual
};
struct Derived : public Base {
    void foo() {            // Derived overrides the pure virtual
        cout << "Hello ";
        Base::foo();    // Call the implementation in the base
        cout << endl;
    }
};

void Base::foo() {
    cout << " world";
}

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

This prints `"Hello world"`, with the `"world"` part coming from the implementation in the base class.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/xoW9Hr)

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment so it makes yours dangle. But +1 for your clear explanation.

Comment: It also means that the class cannot be instantiated, which is a fairly important detail.

Answer (score 4):

C++11 introduced [the `override` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) to help with this:

```
struct Base
{
   void foo();
};

struct Derived : Base
{
   void foo() override;    // error! Base::foo is not virtual
};
```

However you can not write this in `Base` itself to get the same effect; i.e. there is no `mustoverride` specifier. Ultimately, it is none of `Base`'s business as to what derived classes do or don't override.

You *can* keep `Base` abstract whilst providing a "default" definition for your pure virtual functions:

```
struct Base
{
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};

void Base::foo() {}

struct Derived : Base {};  // error! does not override Base::foo
struct Derived2: Base
{
   virtual void foo() override
   {
      Base::foo();   // invokes "default" definition
   }
};
```

This will be an acceptable solution *if you are content for the entire base type to be rendered uninstantiable*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually there is:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void someFun() {std::cout << "Base::fun" << std::endl;}
    virtual  ~Base() {}
};

class AlmostBase : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void someFun() = 0;
};

class Derived : public AlmostBase
{
public:
    virtual void someFun() {std::cout << "Derived::fun" << std::endl;}  
};

int main()
{
    Derived *d = new Derived();
    d->someFun();
    delete d;
}
```

If you uncomment the `someFun` from `Derived` the compiler will complain ...
You introduce an intermediary class `AlmostBase` which has the function as pure virtual. This way you can have `Base` objects too, and the only drawback now is that all your classes will need to inherit from the intermediary base.

Comment: I like this. I guess you could do some clever stuff with `friends` and private constructors to **force** derivation from `AlmostBase` as opposed to `Base`.

Answer (score 1):

A pure-virtual member function can still have a body. The only caveat is that it must be defined outside the class definition. This is perfectly legal C++:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
  virtual void foo() const = 0;
};

void Base::foo() const
{
  std::cout << "Base!\n";
}

struct Derived : Base
{
  // Uncomment following line to remove error:
  //virtual void foo() const override { std::cout << "Derived\n"; Base::foo(); }
};

int main()
{
  Derived d;
  d.foo();
}
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/g0yosx)

Notice that this makes `Base` an abstract class in all respects, i.e. it's impossible to instantiate `Base` directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the base method throw an exception when called, then the class must override it to avoid the parent execution.
this is used in the MFC FrameWork for example

```
// Derived class is responsible for implementing these handlers
//   for owner/self draw controls (except for the optional DeleteItem)
void CComboBox::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)
    { ASSERT(FALSE); }
void CComboBox::MeasureItem(LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT)
    { ASSERT(FALSE); }
int CComboBox::CompareItem(LPCOMPAREITEMSTRUCT)
    { ASSERT(FALSE); return 0; }
```

those methods must be inherited if the control is owner drawn it is responsible for the measuer, draw,... if you missed it while you are testing the function you will get an assert or exception with useful information thrown.